# Read an XML stored in Oracle DB in CLOB Data type

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to read the values from the XML format stored in clob data type in Oracle DB.
from below XML stored in CLOB column i wanted to read the specific values like "entityFldType="uid""
can anyone help me with SQL

```
"d258b8c7-fa47-49d4-a28c-f779d39" xmlns:even="http://www.cos.com/EDA/Event100">
<Body userId="administrator" entityType="USER" internalId="uid=usertest1,ou=People,dc=abcde,dc=medical,dc=com" datasource="LAP">
    <Field entityFldType="uid">
        <value>usertest1</value>
    </Field>
    <Field entityFldType="userPassword">
        <value>********</value>
    </Field>
    <Field entityFldType="telephoneNumber">
        <value>000 00000/55555</value>
    </Field>
    <Field entityFldType="employeeType">
        <value>active</value>
    </Field>
    <Field entityFldType="mail">
        <value>usertest1@coz.com</value>
    </Field>
    <Field entityFldType="initials">
        <value>a</value>
    </Field>
    <Field entityFldType="objectClass">
        <value>top</value>
    </Field>
    <Field entityFldType="sn">
        <value>qa</value>
    </Field>
    <Field entityFldType="cn">
        <value>qa</value>
    </Field>
</Body>
```

</even:Event>

Comment: you need to use Xpath

Answer (score 1):

Your XML got a little mangled, but an easy way is to convert to XMLTYPE which opens up many of the XMLDB features.  So you'll have something along the lines:

```
select 
  extractvalue(my_xml, '/body/field/text()') tag_value,
  extractvalue(my_xml, '/body/field/@entityFldType') attr_value
from ( select xmltype(clob) my_xml from your_table )
```

Comment: [`EXTRACTVALUE` is deprecated.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/EXTRACTVALUE.html#GUID-20AB974B-7544-4F44-B539-787FB6145680)